# Dropping a CHECK in mariadb?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.2

I have a schema migration plan to add json column to mariadb 10.2.
But I am required to have a reverse plan.
Here's the forward plan:

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`table1` 
ADD COLUMN jsonf JSON DEFAULT NULL;

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`table1`
ADD CHECK(JSON_VALID(jsonf)) ;
```

Here's the reverse/rollback plan:

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`table1`
DROP COLUMN jsonf;

DROP CHECK ?
```

What I am confused is how do I reverse the CHECK?
Thank you.

**UPDATE**:

I got error

```
 Kernel error: Error( 4025 ) 23000: "CONSTRAINT `jsonf_is_json` failed for `mydb`.`#sql-8f8_d0c5c1`"
```

when I try to run add constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`table1`
ADD CONSTRAINT jsonf_is_json CHECK(JSON_VALID(jsonf));
```

I use mariadb 10.2.8 if that matters

Answer (score 3):

You must assign a name to the CHECK constraint during add:

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`table1`
ADD CONSTRAINT check_json_validity CHECK(JSON_VALID(jsonf));
```

Then you may freely remove it by name:

```
ALTER TABLE
DROP CONSTRAINT check_json_validity;
```

If you forget to assing the name you may to see it in `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output.

Answer (score 2):

You should always (if possible) name your constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE T ( x int not null );

ALTER TABLE T 
    ADD COLUMN jsonf JSON DEFAULT NULL;

ALTER TABLE T
    ADD CONSTRAINT T_C1 CHECK(JSON_VALID(jsonf)) ; 

ALTER TABLE T DROP CONSTRAINT T_C1;

ALTER TABLE T DROP COLUMN jsonf;
```

If you have anonymous constraints, you can find them in:

```
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
```